# Write session data with dot notation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-variables

I add my session variables like this:

```
foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
  $this->Session->write("MyVariable.$key", $value );
}
```

Is it possible to add element to session variable array without passing the key ?
I mean like this:

```
$MyArray[] = "apple";
$MyArray[] = "banana";
```

So is it possible to add like this? Pseudo code:

```
$this->Session->write('MyVariable'.[], "apple");
$this->Session->write('MyVariable'.[], "banana");
```

Edit: `$data` array was for giving an example. The data that will be saved is not array. It is a string. Everytime I add to session variable I don't want to give key by code. I wonder whether is it possible out of the box. In my current codes I make it like this:

```
    $newKey = count( $this->Session->read("MyVariable") );
    $this->Session->write("MyVariable.$newKey", "apple");
```

Comment: If its already an array why not just storing it like one? `$this->Session->write("MyVariable", $data);`

Answer (score 0):

Hi i guess it should be like this:

```
foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
  $this->Session->write('MyVariable.'.$key, $value );
}
```

You have to place a dot inside the quotation mark.

Comment: Sorry for typo, I edited. I don't want to give key value each time. Just want to push to the end.

Comment: Try something like this `$this->Session->write('MyVariable.'.$newKey[], $value );`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to give the key value each time, then store it as an array like @mark said

```
$this->Session->write("MyVariable", $data);
```

If you want to add a new value to the $data array in some other part of your code, you'll have to do something like

```
$data = $this->Session->read("MyVariable");
$data[] = array('other'=>'value');
$this->Session->write("MyVariable", $data);
```

Or add the exact key like @mmahgoub said

```
$this->Session->write("MyVariable".$key, $value);
```